# What is the etiquette on tags like "delete me" or "troll"?

Tags: discussion, tagging, etiquette

I noticed the creation of tags "delete-me" and "troll," see https://math.stackexchange.com/tags?tab=new for the moment.

I do not know where the latter was used, but I flagged [the question where the former was used](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/895478/question-with-a-boob), so I agree with the message in that case.
Still, I am wondering if it is appropriate to introduce such tags.

1. Is there any established etiquette on marking (by users other than OP) via use of tags inappropriate questions?
2. If not, what should it be?

Answer (score 8):

Tags are removed automatically if they are not used by any question, this happens once every day. So removing the tags from any question that uses it (or just remove the question if appropriate) is a necessary first step.

Tags like this are actively harmful, they serve no useful purpose and just shouldn't be created. Dealing with abusive or troll posts should happen by using spam or offensive flags, tags are the completely wrong tool for this. Six spam or offensive flags delete a post automatically, if you do anything else on spam or troll posts you're wasting your time. Just nuke them with those flags and move on.

As tags can only be created by users with a certain amount of reputation, just flag any post of the user creating abusive tags to make the moderators aware of this. They can then talk to the user or simply stop them from doing any further damage, if necessary.